# The debugger cannot continue. VS2013

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have the problem that if I create a Test project for Windows Phone 8 and want to start it I get the error: "The debugger cannot continue. Unable to start debugging"

I use VS2013 Ultimate the latest Version and work on Windows 8.1 as OS.

The interesting thing is that if I rebuild the project as normal project and add all references they are need to create the test I get another error.

If anybody could help me I will be very glad about it.

Comment: Is Hyper-V running? Can you confirm that? Does it work if you deploy to a physical device?

Comment: I should not forget to say that I use a VM but Hyper-V is not activated. I haven't install a WP-emulator and tried it to deploy it on a physical device as the message pops up.

Comment: You're doing development in a VM? Have you confirmed that the VM is connecting to the phone correctly?

Comment: The really strange thing is I haven't any troubles with a normal C# project for windows phone and no problems by deploying it.

Comment: Further I have tried to reconstruct a test project for windows phone 8 based on a normal windows phone 8 project.
The same references, the same properties, but different behaviour.
I can deploy the app but get an exception by initialising the wrapper:
 var wrapper = new TestExecutorServiceWrapper();
I have no Idea how I can run a working test-project on Windows Phone 8.